# Как оставить скроллбар?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день! Есть скрипт для выдвижного блока. При открытом блоке в стиле для body и html присваивается overflow hidden, а у блока overflow auto/scroll. Как можно сделать, чтобы при открытом блоке скроллбар оставался у body, а не у блока, при этом прокрутка происходила самого открытого блока, но не body? Благодарю!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.sidebar_icon, .sidebar_bg').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var tdata = {
  ".sidebar":    "sidebar_toggled",
  ".sidebar_bg": "sidebar_bg_toggle",
  ".sidebar_icon-close": "icon-close-active",
  ".wrapper":    "wrapper_push",
  "body":        "site-cache"
 };
 var remove = $(this).hasClass("sidebar_bg");
 $.each(tdata, function(sel, cls){
  remove ? $(sel).removeClass(cls) : $(sel).toggleClass(cls);     
 });    
 });
});
```

```css
.sidebar_icon {
    float: right;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000;
}
.sidebar {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -240px;
 width: 240px;
}
.sidebar_toggled {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 width: 240px;
 background: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar_icon"></div>
<div class="sidebar">side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/>side<br/></div>
doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>doc<br/>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidebar_icon, .sidebar_bg').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tdata = {
        ".sidebar":    "sidebar_toggled",
        ".sidebar_bg": "sidebar_bg_toggle",
        ".sidebar_icon-close": "icon-close-active",
        ".wrapper":    "wrapper_push",
        "body":        "site-cache"
    };
    var remove = $(this).hasClass("sidebar_bg");
    $.each(tdata, function(sel, cls){
        remove ? $(sel).removeClass(cls) : $(sel).toggleClass(cls);     
    });    
    });
});
```

Comment: вы не могли бы оформить в виде снипетта, т.е. привести полностью html+css+js код. подробности оформления тут (кнопки нет, но можно вставлять разметку): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers